# Ajax call Always getting error block

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have *jsp* page and I tried to call **ajax** call from *jsp* side and it goes to Java side.

But when I get response from java side to *jsp* side always shows ERROR alert from *jsp* side.

I returned `hashmap` parameter from java side to *jsp* side.

Here are my **ajax** call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function deleteUser(){
       $("#datatable-responsive tr").click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
           var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
          // alert(value);

           $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "deleteUser.html",    
                data :  "id="+ value,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(message) {
                    alert("DELETED");
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
         });
        });
   }   
 </script>
```

At java side, I also debug the code and shows perfect output but when it goes to jsp side with some response it will always goes for ERROR alert.

Does anyone know why this happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to debug the code. Check the console to see what the response text is. Hopefully there should also be an error code you can use to diagnose your issue

Comment: from `url : "deleteUser.html"` i see you are trying to `POST` to a static HTML page, that is not going to work.

Comment: Have you checked what the error is?  Use the all the parameters to error and console.log each of them:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

Comment: I did not get any error it always goes into error block.

Comment: You need to open the console (usually by pressing F12 in your browser). Then check the console for errors. Also check the Network tab *after* making the request. You will see the response in there. Please copy+paste what it states in to your question

Comment: It shows like status code = 406 not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data like 
`data:  {'id':'value'},` it's JSON data it will help at least to find out what is send by your ajax post.